# Include text in Angular 2+ Date Pipe format

Tags: angular, pipe, date-pipe

I am attempting to use the `DatePipe` in Angular 2. I want the output date to be in the format: `08/23/2017 at 11:07 AM`.

However, I can't figure out the proper way to include the text `at` in my date format.

When I specify the format as such: `{{my_date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy at hh:mm a'}}`

I get: `08/23/2017 AMt 11:07 AM`.

I tried surrounding the text in quotes: `{{my_date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy "at" hh:mm a'}}`

But that just added the quotes to the output: `08/23/2017 "AMt" 11:07 AM`.

Is the only way to do this to break it up into two separate pipes with the two sides of the format like `{{my_date | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy}} at {{my_date | date: 'hh:mm a'}}`?

Or is there a way to escape the `a` in `at` so that it will display the text `at` instead of `AMt`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I had this exact situation. I was able to get it to work by surrounding the literal text with `\'`

`{{my_date | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd \'at\' HH:mm:ss'}}`

Comment: For the ones using double quotes (like me), it won't work by adding `\"at\"`, but you will be able to do `myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy 'at' HH:mm"`

Answer (score 2):

May be you can create a simple pipe,

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'dateFormatPipe',
})
export class dateFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string) {
       var datePipe = new DatePipe("en-US");
        value = datePipe.transform(value, 'MMM-dd-yyyy') + ' at ' + datePipe.transform(value, 'hh:mm a');
        return value;
    }

}

<p>{{currentTime | dateFormatPipe}}</p>
```

[Ref1](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/04/date-filtering-and-formatting-using.html) , [Ref2](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/10/how-to-show-date-is-today-or-yesterday.html)