# Angular DatePipe

Tags: angular, date-pipe

I want to display date and time in html like this:

> 19 Jan 2023. at 14:15

I am using this DatePipe:

```
{{order.updatedAt | date: 'dd MMM, y. h:mm a'}}
```

When I place "at" like this: `{{order.updatedAt | date: 'dd MMM, y. at h:mm a'}}`, I am given this result:

[image]

Can you help me guys how to solve this problem?
In [documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe), I don't find any DatePipe which suits me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include text in Angular 2+ Date Pipe format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843532/include-text-in-angular-2-date-pipe-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to write two pipe line code.

```
{{order.updatedAt | date: 'dd MMM, y.'}} at {{order.updatedAt | date: 'h:mm a'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own text (which is not part of the format) by using something like

```
{{order.updatedAt | date: "dd MMM, y. 'at' h:mm a"}}
```